# Create all possible words, by inserting character into existing string

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python/programming. I'm trying to create a list of every possible word by inserting a character into a given string.

e.g.

```
'thx' = ['athx','tahx','thax','thxa']
```

I can accomplish this by splitting my loop with if/else, but i'm trying to solve without it - I can't seem to find a way that will add the character to both the very beginning and very end. (both athx & thxa)

From looking into this, it appears the only way would be with a regular expression. But, I'm not there yet. Really just trying to make sure I'm not missing anything on a more fundamental level.

Comment: hint: `word[:i] + 'a' + word[i:]` inserts the letter `a` into `word` at position `i`. Basically reads "all the letters in `word` up to `i` + 'a' + letters in `word` from `i` to end"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> w = 'thx'
>>> letter = 'a'
>>> words = [w[:i] + letter + w[i:] for i in range(len(w) + 1)]
>>> words 
['athx', 'tahx', 'thax', 'thxa']
```

Comment: Thank you. Very stupid of me not to have tried that. I was under the impression that the w[:0] would return 't'